# Returning to the main Activity after going in settings

Tags: java, android, settings, exit

i'm in the process of making an android app and i have a problem:
at one point i need to check if the user has Usage access settings enabled for the app, if not it goes to the correct settings page with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);        
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, i enter a while loop until the user has activated the setting:

```
while (!CheckPerm()){
        Log.d("info", "waiting for access" );
    }
    Log.d("info", "access granted");
```

It correctly leaves the loop when the acces has been given, but after that i want the settings page to close, and go back to the main view, i've tried with finish(), onBackPressed(), etc and nothing works, also when i press the back button it closes the app.

Comment: Would you please post code on how you are calling the `finish()` method? That should work.

Comment: For now a work around can be opening new page without closing this one.

Comment: i just add a finish after the While loop and it does nothing,i've also tried opening a new page but then if the user uses the return key it goes back to the settings page :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!CheckPerm()){
Log.d("info", "waiting for access" );}
else
{
Log.d("info", "access granted");
    finish()
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is that it won't wait for the user to activate the setting, it will just print "waiting for access" once then leave the function (and the app will crash bc it doesn't have the permission) so i need a loop that waits for the user to switch the setting and then leave, my problem isn't the loop, it's how to exit that "settings" view opened with "startActivity"